# Spring MVC: What happens if I start a thread in a controller action?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

in a Spring MVC Controller I would like to start a thread that continues work while my controller sends the response. Will this work with spring-mvc ?

Best Reagrds,
Heinrich

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it'll work. On one web app I worked on, I needed to send a notification email depending on the user's action. I added a post-commit interceptor on the service, and had that fire off the email in a separate thread. (In my case that happened to be cleaner than putting the code in the controller, because I only wanted it to happen if the transaction committed.)

You do need to make sure the thread actually stops running at some point, either by setting daemon to true (if it's ok that stopping the server kills the thread without notice) or making sure the code in its run method will always terminate at some point.

You are better off using a threadpool than creating new threads, so you don't risk resource exhaustion (threads stalling out are usually not independent events, if a thread hangs the next one probably will too, so you need a way to cut your losses). Methods annotated with @Async will be executed using an executor that you can configure as shown in [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Comment: Perhaps good to mention that the Controller cannot notify the user when sending an email failed (unless you use Callable.get() which kind of defeats the purpose of another thread here).

Comment: If I want to use a thread pool, how can I achieve that there is only one threadpool used for all users/requests on the server? Edit: Can this be done by scoping the threadpool bean to "singleton" ?

Comment: One thing that I don't understand about the @Async is the completable future. I want to queue some background thread but before I do that I need to make some checks and return a result that I have succeffully queued the task. So either I manually call `executor.execute` or use this method. But I caon't seem to be able to access JPA sessions because hibernate throws errors saying session isn't open :/

Answer (score 7):

Yes, You can start new Thread in Controller. But better way of doing asynchronous job is to use spring-scheduling support. You can leverage Quartz framework. That will manage your job.

This [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) will give you how to integrate this in your application.

Comment: Can you go a bit into why using spring-scheduling/Quartz is better than starting a new Thread in this case?

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned, it's will work. `ExecutorService` can do the job. Here you can see I used it for starting a video stream that sits on a separate endpoint.

```
@PostMapping("/capture")
public ResponseEntity capture() {
    // some code omitted
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    service.submit(() -> startStreaming(deviceConfig));
    return return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .body(stream);
}
```